# CakePHP: pagination and custom routes

Tags: cakephp, routes, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I don't seem to be able to use a custom route with pagination. The URL of the blog should be `http://www.domain.com/en/page:2`. However, the links generated by the PaginateHelper (prev and next), keep adding the controller and action, so that the URL looks like `http://www.domain.com/posts/index/en/page:2`.

The route config is quite simple:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:lang/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        'lang' => '[a-z]{2}',
        'pass' => array(
            'lang'
        )
    )
);
```

I set this in the view:

```
$paginator->options(
    array(
        'url' => $this->passedArgs
    )
);
```

and also to set the path manually not using an array

this happens with Cake 1.33

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems prev and next method of Paginator helper doesn't use default options. That's why

```
$paginator->options(
    array(
        'url' => $this->passedArgs
    )
);
```

doesn't work. You can set it on prev and next method directly. For example:

```
$paginator->prev('<< Previous', array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem (still the same: Cake keeps adding the controller + action to the URL where it shouldn't). I will track that towards core in the next days ..

Comment: aargh .. I found it: passedArgs did only contain the var `lang`. When I added the controller and action to the index it worked. Thanks again

Comment: @harpax How'd you solve the problem can you share this as an answer please